# @XmlElement and @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)

Tags: java, xml

I have a strange behaviour, and I don't understand it.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Object {
@XmlElement(name = "object")
private List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<Object>();

    public List<Object> getObjectList() {
        return objectList;
    }
}
```

This part should hold values for each object.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Object {
    @XmlElement
    private int id;
    private int value;
}
```

I don't understand why are there values passed into the `id` and `value` fields. Is it necessary to write `@XmlElement` if the names are the same?

Comment: It is a good practice to hint all field what you handle, for example you can add special name or extra rules, but not necessary.